# This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.4 or newer

Tags: android-studio

This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.4 or newer.

but my android studio version is 3.2.1 and there is no new update from Google

Comment: I've had this happen before where it forces you to update to cannery channel

Answer (score 116):

Try to edit your project build.gradle file and set the android build gradle plugin to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` within the dependency section.

See also the [documentation of the android grade plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin)

Comment: maybe there is also the wrong distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties. I have to set 'distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-bin.zip' there

Answer (score 61):

It's a bit late, But easy and effective.
Click on About Android Studio,
Check the current version,
Open build.gradle of Project and put it in front of the class path. e.g Your studio version is 3.5.2, then your classpath should look like this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
```

Comment: This advice also worked for me on Android Studio 4.0.1. My project's `build.gradle` file was using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0rc2'`, and failing with the error message "...retry with version 4.1 or newer". When I changed the Gradle library version to `4.0.1`, the problem went away.

Comment: 3.5.2 its perfect for me. bellow that possible `gradle ASCII: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'`

Answer (score 38):

You would need to lower your gradle version and android plugin version, or you can download latest version from beta or canary update channels.

To enable updates from other channels go to Help -> Check for Updates  -> Congifure automatic updates and in that dialog select channel you want. After selecting check for update again and it will show you latest version.

[image]

Comment: I advise against automatic update, specially if you work on a team with several people on the same project. Android Studio updates should be planned; as you will with any library update. Had lead to builds broken several times in the past.

Answer (score 19):

This issue is caused due to use of newer version of gradle in the project.
There are two options to resolve this:

**Option 1:**
Change `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Change project level gradle `build.gradle` file

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2")
```

**Option 2:**
Update your Android Studio to newer version. **(Highly recommended)**

Comment: If you’re afraid of updating Android Studio and possibly breaking your project, remember that you can have multiple Android Studio version on your machine.

Answer (score 10):

In IntelliJ IDEA this is an open bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252823

As a workaround, you can change the build tools version as other people advise.

My project was failing with this dependency:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha03
```

Now it's working with this:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2
```

As a side note, you should change that dependency in `build.gradle` in some projects or in `dependencies.kt` in newer projects.

That was the most updated version that worked.

Answer (score 5):

After an update the Android Studio does not show the layout's design for some reason. I tried newer versions as well, but it did not work. So I decided to downgrade my IDE.

When I opened my project, I got the same error. The solution was the following:

1. Open the **Project Structure**.
2. Select the **Project** field.
3. Use the appropriate **Android Plugin Version**. You can copy it from a new project's structure.
4. Change the **Gradle version** too what you need.
5. OK.
6. Find the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and open it.
7. Change the **distributionUrl** to that gradle version url what you saved in the Project Structure.

Or if you don't mind, then you can update your AS.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same Issue when i decided to install another version of Android Studio, what worked for me was:

- Creating a new project with the current version of Android Studio just to go check the classpath version at the project level **build.gradle** inside the dependencies section, at the time it was this:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-rc01'`

Copied that line and replaced it on the project i was working on.

Answer (score 5):

in project's `build.gradle` file comment `classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:`. File → Project Structure select Android Gradle Plugin Version to match Android Studio version

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 4):

You can now update your **android studio** to **3.4** **stable version**. Updates for stable version are now available. cheers!!!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered with this error and just decrease gradle version and android plugin version to 5.1.1 and 3.4.2.

Answer (score 3):

i just change gradle version  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'` to 
 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'` and now working.

Answer (score 2):

Close VPN worked for me! It suprised me.

Answer (score 1):

this issue occur for me after downgrade Java JDK, after upgrade JDK my problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Open android studio then go to help menu > check for update > Update your Android Studio to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

If u r here because of Jetpack Compose, I had the same problem, and solved it by using the Arctic Fox Canary build of Android studio: you can download it at this link: https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/ide-zips/2020.3.1.12/android-studio-2020.3.1.12-mac.zip

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises due to updates, You can resolve this by downgrading the gradle used from
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 to a previous gradle like  com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0 or anything older than the current one

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you're opening someone else's project after unzipping it. And the person has used an updated android Studio.

The way to solve it is

1.Go to Help and about to see your android studio version
2.Go to File>Project Structure> and set your Android Gradle Plugin version to your android studio version
3.Change the Gradle version to the one you usually use.(optional)

Build the project and it should run without any errors

Comment: Is there any way to check the android gradle plugin version compatiblity with respect to android studio version?

Comment: Not that i know of

Answer (score 0):

This seems like incompatible gradle plugin vs gradle binary versions. You can find the releases here: [Gradle Plugin release and compatiblity](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Upgrade your grade plugin and grade binary to compatible versions and the app should start building.