# Upgrade Android Studio 3.6 or newer

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, upgrade

I am having an issue with my Gradle just this day. It was working fine just recently and I haven't done anything just now and I see this. Please help.

````
java.lang.RuntimeException: This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.6 or newer. ```
````

Comment: Which version of AS are you using? Post your build.gradle file

Comment: really android studio 6.3 ?? because currently latest version is 3.5.*.  what do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.4 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331462/this-version-of-android-studio-cannot-open-this-project-please-retry-with-andro)

Comment: Check if your are using a plugin version as `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-beta01'` (an revert to 3.5) or some feature like `viewBinding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your projects `build.gradle` file, and change `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.X.X`(where X is the current version) to match your current version of android studio 
 - to check your current version of Android Studio go to "Help - About"

The issue you're having happened most likely because you have activated beta builds in Android Studio, and you have accepted Android Studios suggestion popup where it suggested upgrading your build tools and gradle plugin

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:
**1) Update android studio
2) Change gradle file**

Comment: Maybe before changing something it is better to understand the root cause of the issue.