# I can't open the project on AndroidStudio from Google Codelab

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to open the project from Codelab but I get this error:

**This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.1 or newer.**

I have cloned the project from gitHub and I'm already on 4.1 and I still can't open it. Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: can you give the repo link of the project, so that we can figure out

Comment: this is the link https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-unscramble-app/tree/starter

Comment: Use this link to clone  https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-unscramble-app.git

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with the new link

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331462/this-version-of-android-studio-cannot-open-this-project-please-retry-with-andro) may solve your issue

Comment: And you may need to update the plugins of the studio.

Comment: I think it wasn't working because I updated the gradle. I unistalled Android Studio and installed it again and it worked